# problemas con apostrofes

Tags: php

Debo introducir nombres en una base de datos.
Desde un archivo con un formulario envio los nombres a otro archivo que lo carga en la BD y me devuelve a la primera página.
He conseguido que los nombres se carguen en la BD, pero al volver a la primera los apostrofes se codifican con otro formato y no me los reconoce la primera página.
No consigo resolver el problema.
He simplificado los archivos para probar.
Se puede probar aquí, al poner una palabra con apostrofe no funciona.
https://menus.cat/vins/cat/primera.php
Codifica el apostrofe con &#039 en lugar de %27

primera.php

```
<?php
session_start();
 //   $nomvi = htmlspecialchars($_GET['nom'], ENT_QUOTES); 
    $nomvi2 = stripslashes($_GET['nom']);
    echo $nomvi2;
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<div class="caixa">
    <form align="center"  method="post" class="contact_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="segona.php";?>
    <input type='text' name='nomvi' id='nomvi'>
    <button class="guardar" type='submit'  name="guardar" id="guardar">Guardar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

segona.php

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</html>    

<?php
session_start();
$nomvi = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nomvi'], ENT_QUOTES);
$nomvi2 = addslashes($nomvi);
echo $nomvi2;
    $url="primera.php?nom=$nomvi2";
    echo "<SCRIPT>window.location='$url';</SCRIPT>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón por lo que codifica el apóstrofe como &#039 es que utilizas la función `htmlspecialchars()`, que convierte los caracteres a HTML.

Si el valor va a ser utilizado en una URL, tienes dos opciones. La que para mí es más óptima, `filter_input()` (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.filter-input.php), o usando `urlencode()` (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode) y `urldecode()` (https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode).

Yo usuaría `filter_input()` por razones de seguridad, ya que filtra el valor.

Te pongo los ejemplos:

**primera.php:**

```
<?php

// Opción con filter_input()

$nomvi = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'nomvi', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

if ( ! empty($nomvi)) {
    echo $nomvi;
}

// Opción con urldecode()

if (isset($_GET['nomvi'])) {
    echo urldecode($_GET['nomvi']); // o echo $_GET['nomvi'], a secas
}

?>
<form method="post" action="segona.php">
    <input type="text" name="nomvi" value="a'pos'tro'fe">
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**segona.php:**

```
<?php

// Opción con filter_input()

$nomvi = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nomvi', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);

if ( ! empty($nomvi)) {
    echo "<script>window.location='primera.php?nomvi=" . $nomvi . "';</script>";
}

// Opción con urlencode()

if (isset($_POST['nomvi'])) {
    echo "<script>window.location='primera.php?nomvi=" . urlencode($_POST['nomvi']) . "';</script>";
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, ya funciona. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Genial, me alegro. Recuerda seguir las instrucciones cuando alguien facilita una respuesta válida, puede ayudar a otras personas en un futuro: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers